# Button state issue

Tags: arduino-uno, button

Let me preface this by saying I'm a beginner, and I know my code must have some logic errors. I need some fresh eyes on this, I have been messing with it a few days and am just running in circles at this point.

I'm trying to use buttons and button states to set hours and minutes of an alarm clock so I am trying to save the state of the buttons so after being pushed so it will remember the state rather than being changed on release. 
I am trying to get it so pushing button A in my code goes into the alarm clock set procedure, then until button C is pressed it will loop to set hours then minutes (I havent added minutes procedure yet) So button A starts procedure and button C completes it, while button B increases the hours/minutes variable by one.

I have thoroughly confused myself. I have two "lastButtonState" variables which may be unnecessary but it was the only thing I could think of.

Right now with my code it goes into the button C while loop but doesn't come out of it on button press. My logic for that was that the while loop should exit when button C is pressed, so I don't think I need anything within the loop to break out of it.

I have the button B setting hours part working, it just isn't exiting the button C loop.

I'm eventually going to put this code in its respective function and add in the set minutes area after set hours area.

Here is my code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
//Constants
//const int buttonPin = 9;
const int buttonApin = 3;
const int buttonBpin = 2;
const int buttonCpin = 5;
int buttonState = 0;
int buttonState2 = 0;
int buttonState3 = 0;
//int flag = 0;
int alarmHoursInner = 1;
int lastButtonState = 0;
int lastButtonState3 = 0;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Input or output?
  pinMode(buttonApin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonBpin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonCpin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonApin);
  buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonBpin);
  buttonState3 = digitalRead(buttonCpin);

  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    while (buttonState3 == LOW) {

      buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonBpin);
      if (lastButtonState != buttonState2) { // last button state starts at 0 (or OFF) this line tests current state against last state
        if (buttonState2 == LOW) { // if buttonState is HIGH it went from OFF to ON
          // Serial.print("Button B works!");
          ++alarmHoursInner; // increments variable for hours
          Serial.print(alarmHoursInner); // prints hours
          Serial.println("  "); // blank line
          delay(50); // delay
        }
        else {

          Serial.print("Please push button B");
          Serial.println("  ");
        }
      }  

      lastButtonState = buttonState2;
    }
      lastButtonState3 = buttonState3;
  }
}
```

Comment: start by renaming the buttons to some useful names that describe the function.... instead of `buttonA`, `buttonB`, `buttonC` call them something like `mode`, `advance`, `exit` .... `modeButton`, etc.

Comment: research `Arduino state machine`

Comment: Ok your input about renaming is noted, thanks! I have already looked at state changes pretty thoroughly. Could you point me in the direction of something specific about state machines that would help? I googled it and looked at a few links but what part of state machines should I focus on? So far, It looks like its what I have already known about states when I developed my code. What exactly is wrong with my code?

Comment: `lastButtonState3 = buttonState3;`  .... this line is indented too far, which makes it look like it is part of the `if` statement .... it is at the end of the `while` loop  ..... `buttonState3` will always be LOW when this line executes